# Take a pair of spinners and extract two strings

Tags: android

I have two spinners that are working, i.e. showing the values stored inside when I click on them.

I need a string out of each of the spinners that is the selected item from each such as "A", and "min7", and I need to combine the two to make a chord like "Amin7'.  Seems simple.

Here's my question:  The user selects "A", and in the onItemSelected code, I am extracting it via 'parentgetItemAtPosition(pos)' then setting the text of an EditText to display the "A" on the screen.

If I can do that, I can fire the second one as well and have my whole Chord displayed.

My code seems logical, but I'm missing something because the "A" never appears.

Here's some of the relevant code:

```
public class SpinnerActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {


        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                   int pos, long id) {
            // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
            // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_song);
            EditText tv1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
            tv1.setText(pos);
            tv1.append(" , "); //comma separted list



        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think mistake is here

```
parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
tv1.setText(pos);
```

and should be

```
tv1.setText(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos));
```